# Memory dump analysis for asp.net web api application shows caching related objects consuming memory

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, memory-leaks

We have a very heavily used asp.net web API app running as azure app service. The application shows memory usage trend as shown below i.e. the memory usage keeps on increasing and never comes down till it gets restarted (using Azure auto healing).
[image]

To further analyze we took 3 memory dumps i.e.

1. first dump after restarting the app
2. Ran a load test and took second dump
3. Again ran the same load test and took third dump

Below is how the comparison between dumps look like

Between 1st and 2nd dump.

[image]

Between 2nd and 3rd dump

[image]

In all these comparisons It seems maximum memory usage increase happens in some caching related objects e.g. ExpiresBucket, RuntimeCache, MemoryCache, CacheExpires etc.

I am not an expert and not sure what exactly these classes do and from where this increase is coming from.
Can somebody throw some light on what these objects mean and is this normal?
Just to be clear we have seen trend and see that memory only increases and never comes down.

Comment: Memory cache with long expiration or too many objects matches the symptoms. Go back to your source code to review any memory caching usage (or a third party framework used), and then determine if that's really what you want to cache that much. If you are familiar with dump analysis, you might also dump out the objects in caches so as to help identify where they came from.

Comment: Thanks.I'll look into that.